# hadoop streaming ensuring one key per reducer

Tags: hadoop, amazon-emr, hadoop-streaming

I have a mapper that, while processing data, classifies output into 3 different types (type is the output key). My goal is to create 3 different csv files via the reducers, each with all of the data for one key with a header row.

The key values can change and are text strings.

Now, ideally, i would like to have 3 different reducers and each reducer would get only one key with it's entire list of values.

Except, this doesn't seem to work because the keys don't get mapped to specific reducers.

The answer to this in other places has been to write a custom partitioner class that would map each desired key value to a specific reducer. This would be great except that I need to use streaming with python and i am not able to include a custom streaming jar in my job so that seems not an option.

I see [in the hadoop docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/streaming.html#Hadoop+Partitioner+Class) that there is an alternate partitioner class available that can enable secondary sorts, but it isn't immediately obvious to me that it is possible, using either the default or key field based partitioner, to ensure that each key ends up on it's own reducer without writing a java class and using a custom streaming jar.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**Examples**:

mapper output:

csv2\tfieldA,fieldB,fieldC
csv1\tfield1,field2,field3,field4
csv3\tfieldRed,fieldGreen
...

the problem is that if i have 3 reducers i end up with key distribution like this:

```
reducer1        reducer2        recuder3
csv1            csv2
csv3
```

one reducer gets two different key types and one reducer gets no data sent to it at all. this is because the hash(key csv1) mod 3 and hash(key csv2) mod 3 result in the same value.

Comment: Hadoop will by default send all of data with the same key to the same reducer. Can you give some examples of what you are trying to do and how it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure MultipleOutputFormat [1] can be used under streaming. That'll solve most of your problems.

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html

Comment: that is exactly what i need and would totally solve my problem, but i can't figure out how to use it with streaming. people have suggested creating a new streaming.jar file with the MultipleOutputFormat code included but i haven't found any good tutorial on doing that and I'd really rather not go that far if I can avoid it.

Comment: I'm making this the answer -- you can use this under streaming if you create your own jar with a subclass of MultipleOutputFormat that creates directories / filenames in accord with the keys and generates a null actual key. I wanted to avoid java and luckily there is a clojure project out there that does exactly what I need: https://github.com/jblomo/oddjob ... the instructions on how to build/use it are on the github page.

Comment: Hey the link seems to be broken.

Comment: This answer is 7 years old so I imagine you don't want to be using r0.20 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck with streaming, and can't include any external jars for a custom partitioner, then this is probably not going to work the way you want it to without some hacks.

If these are absolute requirements, you *can* get around this, but it's messy.

Here's what you can do:

Hadoop, by default, uses a hashing partitioner, like this:

`key.hashCode() % numReducers`

So you can pick keys such that they hash to 1, 2, and 3 (or three numbers such that `x % 3 = 1, 2, 3`). This is a nasty hack, and I wouldn't suggest it unless you have no other options.

Comment: this is essentially what i decided i would need to do to achieve this. but it is so cumbersome that i have decided to use a single reducer outputting original keys with final csv lines and then run my output file through `cat part-00000 | grep key | cut -f 2 > key.csv` for each key. i loose parallelism in my reducer and i have to post-process my output, but whatever i do seems hacky and ugly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want custom output to different csv files you can direct write (with API) to hdfs. As you know hadoop passes with key and associated value list to single reduce task. In reduce code, check , while key is same write to same file. If another key comes, create new file manually and write into it. It does not matter how many reducers you have

Comment: this doesn't seem like a bad idea... thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Good call. With Python streaming reducers, he can ship the (zipped) Python HDFS libs to the task nodes with the -file argument, and then use the Python zipimport module to import them.